# Boot 32bit UEFI from file

Tags: linux, boot, bios, uefi

I have linux on usb(32bit x86) and two PCs,

1. one an laptop 64x uefi boots fine.
2. one tablet having 64bit processor [but 32bit uefi-bios](http://thinksilicon.de/74/HowTo-openSUSE-13-2-auf-Odys-Winpad-V10-installieren.html) do not boot.

The second one has no option for legacy boot, but it has the possibillity to boot from `.efi`-File.

Unfortunately none of the `.efi`-files ...

- /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
- /efi/boot/grubx64.efi

... loads and give the same message: `\efi\boot\bootx64.efi boot failed`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your system is not capable of booting a 32-bit kernel while in UEFI mode.  So either use legacy mode or use a 64-bit kernel.  Since only one is possible, your options are limited, none of those files are meant for a 32-bit operating system.  They both specifically indicate 64-bit.

Comment: how can that even be possible: a 32-bit linux having 64-bit `.efi`-File!?

Comment: *It isn't possible.*  The EFI files are only for the 64-bit installation on the disk.

Comment: It is possible to do what Peter is asking; it's just a very bleeding-edge configuration. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 2):

EFIs support programs, including boot loaders, of like bit depth. In other words, an x86-64 (aka AMD64, x64, or EM64T) EFI can launch a 64-bit binary, which normally has a filename ending in `x64.efi`; and an x86 (aka IA32, i686 or related) EFI can launch a 32-bit binary, which normally has a filename ending in `ia32.efi`. Note that, if you have a 32-bit EFI, the bit depth of the CPU is irrelevant. The result is that your system with a 32-bit EFI and 64-bit CPU is limited to running 32-bit EFI programs.

Normally, the bit depth of the EFI boot loader (which is just a particular type of EFI program) also limits the bit depth of the OS it runs. Thus, it's easiest to install a 32-bit OS on a computer with a 32-bit EFI. There are ways around this limit, though. In particular, both Apple's OS X boot loader and Linux's GRUB support cross-bit-depth kernel booting, so you can launch a 64-bit kernel from a 32-bit boot loader or vice-versa. (Obviously, you need a 64-bit CPU to launch a 64-bit kernel.) Since you say you're using Linux, but don't say what distribution you're using, I can't give very detailed instructions -- and in fact I don't have the details handy. Such cross-bit-depth installations are very much "bleeding edge," and I recommend avoiding them if at all possible.

Sticking with a 32-bit OS is likely to be easier, but many OSes (including most Linux distributions) have neglected 32-bit EFIs, so you may need to add a boot loader yourself. This process is described for Ubuntu [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392719/32-bit-uefi-boot-support) IIRC, Debian now provides 32-bit EFI support, so you might get it working "out of the box."

Ultimately, to have one disk that's bootable on both 32-bit and 64-bit EFIs, with BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode boot support out of the question, you'll need to install both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of a boot loader, and configure one to boot in a cross-bit-depth manner. It's likely to be better to have two disks, or at least two installations on one disk, one being 32-bit and the other 64-bit. For an external disk, the 32-bit boot loader will be `EFI/BOOT/bootia32.efi` and the 64-bit boot loader will be `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`.